# $.grep returns empty array even when match occurs

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm really confused why my grep function is not working. I have an array of objects like so:

```
$scope.kit = [{id: 1, producer: "company", category: "hardware" }, 
              {id: 2, producer: "company2", category: "hardware"}];
```

And i'm trying to remove id 2 using grep, I thought I would do:

```
$scope.kit = 
$.grep($scope.kit, function(e) {
    e.id != 2;
});
```

Yet, all I get is an empty array each time. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not *returning* the boolean expression. You should provide it as `return` value:

```
return  e.id != 2;
```

Without `return`, `e.id != 2;` doesn't do anything: the result of that expression disappears into oblivion. Then the return value of the `$.grep` callback function is `undefined` for all elements, which is falsy, and so none of the elements match, resulting in an empty array.

Comment: _"You need to return the value"_.. Probably a Boolean...And `undefined` is `falsey` value... +1

Comment: Yes, but that is not the problem as `e.id != 2` is a boolean expression.

Comment: Yeah but _You need to return the value_ seems incomplete to me... Under this context, it is fine..

Comment: Taking your comments to heart, I made a little update.

Answer (score 1):

use return in grep function.

```
$.grep($scope.kit, function(e) {
    return e.id != 2;
});
```

As per the jquery docs http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/

**The function should return a Boolean value**